# Fbprophet installs infinitely

Tags: pip, windows-10, pystan

I'm having trouble installing fbprophet on my Windows 10, I'm not sure whether the problem lies within pystan or fbprophet actually. Once the installation starts it just keeps on going [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkbio.png)
Has anyone ran into similar problem and managed to solve it?

Comment: you solved it somehow? i have the same problem

Comment: I'm don't remember that well honestly, I think it installed rather easily when I switched to Linux, but I'm not sure about windows. I'll try to dig a bit when I'm back at my pc, but no promises. Sorry mate